# Navigation bar issue html

Tags: html, navigationbar

I have created a website and I have included in that website a navigation bar, the navigation bar works good on all the pages except for the contact page. I have created in the contact page a form and set its background to light pink, but the navigation bar is mostly light pink, rather than the navigation bar's colour. Here is my navigation bar code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600');
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background: #222;
      font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
    }

    .container {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    header {
      background: #55d6aa;
    }

    header::after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .logo {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    nav {
      float: right;
    }

    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 100px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      position: relative;
    }

    nav a {
      color: #444;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    nav a:hover {
      color: #000;
    }

    nav a::before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #444;

      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 0%;

      transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    }

    nav a:hover::before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #d3d3d3
      }
      table, th, td {
        border:2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Playfair;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .header {
        padding: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgb(183, 203, 211);
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    </style>
    <header>
      <div class = "container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/home"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QkMky9F/logo1.png" 
    alt="logo1" border="0" width = "200" height = "100"></a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Here is my form code:

```html
        <h2><center><font color = "blue">Contact us form</font></center></h2>
        <style>
        body {font-family: Arial, Cursive, Bodoni 72;}
        * {box-sizing: border-box;}

        input[type = text], select, textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-top: 6px;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            resize: vertical;
        }

        input[type = submit] {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        input[type = submit]:hover {
            background-color:black;
        }

         .container {
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #e9c1c1;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        </style>
        <div class = "container">
            <label for = "First name">First name</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "First name" name = "First name" placeholder = "Please enter 
    your first name...">

            <label for = "Last name">Last name</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Last name" name = "Last name" placeholder = "Please enter 
    your last name...">

            <label for = "country">Country</label>
            <select id = "country" name = "country">
                <option value = "Select a country">Select the country</option>
                <option value = "Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value = "England">England</option>
                <option value = "italy">Italy</option>

            <label for = "Subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id = "Subject" name = "Subject" placeholder = "Please write if you want to 
    contact me..." style = "height: 200px"></textarea>

            <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit">
        </div>
        <p><center>To go to the homepage, please go to the homepage:<br><br><a href = 
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home">Homepage</a></center></p>
        <br><p><center>For more information about me and my family, please go to the profile page: 
   <br><br><a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/profile">Profile page</a></center></p>
        <br><p><center>For more information about me, please go to the about page:<br><br><a href 
    = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/about">About page</a></center></p>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <style>
            .footer{
                position: fixed;
                left: 10px;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: gray;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
```

Here is the navigation bar in other pages:

[image]

Here is the navigation bar in contact page:

[image]

Can somebody please help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extra CSS on the contact page:

```css
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #e9c1c1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

is matching your navigation bar wrapper element since the navigation bar wrapper has the `container` class on it.

You can should change this class name so it is different from your navigation bar wrapper element class:

```css
.different-class-name {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #e9c1c1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- […] -->
<div class = "different-class-name">
    <label for = "First name">First name</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "First name" name = "First name" placeholder = "Please enter 
    your first name...">
    <!-- […] -->
```

Comment: Wongjn thank you so much, I will let you know if it works or not.